# In Studio, when switching color filter to "Available colors in BrickLink" all bricks have no color available and pricing is missing

Tags: colour, bricklink, bricklink-studio

As soon as I switch color filter to "Available colors in BrickLink" all bricks have no color available - even what I assume are the most common brick types... I also appear to receive no pricing information for any brick! This must be some kind of error of correct live information feeding into the application - do you know how I can check and I solve this?

This is on BrickLink Studio version 2.23.12 (1)

Comment: Your question is missing some important information that would be useful for being able to answer it. I'm presuming you are using BrickLink Studio, but you should make sure to state that as well as the version (From the Help menu, select About Studio) to make sure that people will be able to answer accurately.